# Laravel Shows White Screen with HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I'm having a weird issue where Laravel doesn't work under HTTPS but works fine under http.

If I go to my homepage '/', it works. But if I try to navigate to any other route, it gives me a white screen.

There are no logs in the storage/logs, nginx error logs are empty, and the nginx access logs show that a request is recieved.

Things I've done:

**1. I've echoed out code by modidfying the index.php The crash happens somewhere with this is called:**

public/index.php

```
echo 'Working!';
$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();
echo 'Crashes';
```

**2. I've commented out all my middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php. Still happens**

Any this ONLY happens when HTTPS is activated, but works with http. Any ideas what this might be?

Comment: Does that white screen result from any error? What's the HTTP response code?

Comment: Check if the rewriting module is working in case of `HTTPS` configuration

Comment: I've turned debug to true. Its hard to diagnose because I'm getting nothing in any logs except the access log.

Comment: Can you check disk. May be it is full.

Comment: What's the HTTP response code? What else did you try to resolve the problem, like: add some var dump, trigger fatal errors,....

Comment: @NicoHaase its  a response 200 with just a white screen.

Comment: What else did you try to resolve the problem? Why not run the code using XDebug or Blackfire to inspect it further?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the issue was in your **app/Http/TrustProxies.php**, you have the have this line:

`protected $proxies = '*';`

You likely get this if you have https terminating at the load balancer, and routed to an HTTP port on an instance (we're on AWS and have this setup).

You can fine tune it to make it trust only certain proxies but this issue will throw no error message in any location to help you debug it.